# Irssi, identical rooms on two servers

Tags: irc, irssi

I connect to two servers with my irssi irc client at the same time. Let's call them serverA and serverB. Both servers have a chat room called #xyz. However when I join #xyz it only connects me to the room on serverA. But I want to connect to the irc room with the same name on serverB. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *server tags* to select the server on which to join the channel.

The `/SERVER` command will show you the servers you are connected to:

```
16:42 -!- atw-inter: irc.atw-inter.net:6667 ()
16:42 -!- servercentral: servercentral.il.us.quakenet.org:6667 ()
```

In my case the tags are *atw-inter* and *servercentral*.

Now to join a channel on a specific server use the `/JOIN` command with the related server tag. So to join the channel *#xyz* on *servercentral.il.us.quakenet.org:6667* use:

```
/JOIN -servercentral #xyz
```

The `/HELP` command gives more info about the commands and options.